# Using merge:true with nested navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Per the RN documentation, the proper way to use `merge` is as follows:

```
navigation.navigate({
  name: 'Post',
  params: { postTitle: 'An okay post' },
  merge: true,
});
```

I'd like to use `merge` in my app, however my navigate function looks a bit different:

```
navigation.navigate("mainScreen", { screen: "secondaryScreen" })
```

I want the route params that were initially passed to `mainScreen` to persist. I know that I can use `merge: true` like in the documentation. However my navigate function is a bit different, and I'm not sure where to put `merge:true`. Is there a proper place for this, or is there a way that I can translate my navigate function to look like the one in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

```
navigation.navigate({
   name: 'mainScreen',
   params: { screen: secondaryScreen },
   merge: true,
});
```

But if you're coding in Typescript, you will get a [compilation error](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10169). I have the same problem. I end up adding @ts-ignore to ignore the type checking.